# How to make a bash script classify files in folders by a specific number

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix

I found a script, here on StackOverflow, which I modified a little. 
The script classifies all files from a folder in subfolders, each subfolder having only 8 files. But I have files with such names 0541_2pcs.jpg. 2pcs means two pieces (copies).

so I would like the script to take this into count when dividing files to each folder. e.g. a folder may have 6 files and this 0541_2pcs.jpg which literally means 2 files and so on, depending on the number indicated in the file's name.

This is the script:

```
cd photos;
dir="${1-.}"
x="${1-8}"

let n=0
let sub=0
while IFS= read -r file ; do
    if [ $(bc <<< "$n % $x") -eq 0 ] ; then
            let sub+=1
            mkdir -p "Page-$sub"
            n=0
    fi

    mv "$file" "Page-$sub"
    let n+=1
done < <(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your requirements are not very clear. Are you trying to say that all files with the prefix `0541_` should be moved to a subdirectory of their own?

Comment: Link to the question / answer where you found the original script here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a test for whether a file name contains the string "2pcs" via code like `[ ${file/2pcs/x} != $file ]`.  In the script shown below, if that test succeeds then `n` is incremented a second time.  Note, if the eighth file tested for inclusion in a directory is a multi-piece file, you will end up with one too many files in that directory.  That could be handled by additional testing the script doesn't do. Note, there's no good reason for your script to call `bc` to do a modulus, and setting both of `dir` and `x` from the first parameter doesn't work; my script uses two parameters.

```
#!/bin/bash

# To test pagescript, create dirs four and five in a tmp dir.
# In four, say
#    for i in {01..30}; do touch $i.jpg; done
#    for i in 03 04 05 11 16 17 18; do mv $i.jpg ${i}_2pcs.jpg; done
# Then in the tmp dir, say
#     rm -rf Page-*; cp four/* five/; ../pagescript five; ls -R

#cd photos;   # Leave commented out when testing script as above
dir="${1-.}"  # Optional first param is source directory
x=${2-8}      # Optional 2nd param is files-per-result-dir

let n=x
let sub=0
for file in $(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f)
do  # Uncomment next line to see values as script runs 
    #echo file is $file, n is $n, sub is $sub, dir is $dir, x is $x
    if [ $n -ge $x ]; then
        let sub+=1
        mkdir -p Page-$sub
        n=0
    fi
    mv "$file" Page-$sub
    [ ${file/2pcs/x} != $file ] && let n+=1
    let n+=1
done
```